# Read Text Files and Save Datas in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to read some text files under different categories and build a linked list which consist of different words from these text files and total number of times this words occur in text files. Linked list should be in alphabetical order. But when I run the code just three different words printed hundreds of times and their occur values are always 1. There is no problem reading all words. I tested it by adding printf statements in while loops and it prints all words correctly. I guess insert function has some problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h >
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct Term {
    char * termName;
    int occur;
    struct Term * next;
} term;

term * insert(term * root, char * word);

int main (void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");

    FILE *fPtr;

    int counter = 1;

    char path[50];

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\econ\\%d.txt", counter);

    term * terms;
    terms = NULL;

    while (fPtr = fopen(path, "r")) {
        while(!feof(fPtr)) {
            char word[20];          
            fscanf(fPtr, "%s", &word);
            terms = insert(terms, word);
        }
        fclose(fPtr);   
        counter++;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\econ\\%d.txt", counter);
    }

    counter = 1;
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\health\\%d.txt", counter);   

    while (fPtr = fopen(path, "r")) {
         while(!feof(fPtr)) {
            char word[20];          
            fscanf(fPtr, "%s", &word);
            terms = insert(terms, word);
        }
        fclose(fPtr);   
        counter++;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\health\\%d.txt", counter);
    }

    counter = 1;
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\magazin\\%d.txt", counter);

    while (fPtr = fopen(path, "r")) {
        while(!feof(fPtr)) {
            char word[20];          
            fscanf(fPtr, "%s", &word);
            terms = insert(terms, word);
        }
        fclose(fPtr);
        counter++;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "dataset\\magazin\\%d.txt", counter);
    }

    fclose(fPtr);

    while (terms -> next != NULL) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", terms -> termName, terms -> occur);
        terms = terms -> next;
    }
}

term * insert(term * root, char * word) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
        root -> next = NULL;
        root -> termName = word;
        root -> occur = 1;
        return root;
    } else if((strcmp(root-> termName, word)) < 0) {
        term * temp = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
        temp -> termName = word;
        temp -> occur = 1;
        temp -> next = root;
        return temp;
    } else {
        term * iter = root;
        while ((iter -> next != NULL) && (strcmp(iter -> termName, word) > 
0)) {           
            iter = iter -> next;
            if (strcmp(iter -> termName, word) == 0) {
                iter -> occur += 1;
                return root;
            }
        }       
        term * temp = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
        temp -> next = iter -> next;
        iter -> next = temp;
        temp -> termName = word;
        temp -> occur = 1;
        return root;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line (and the others like it) are the problem.

```
temp -> termName = word;
```

You're assigning whatever `word` is pointing to which is the array you declare here:

```
char word[20];
```

Which is limited in scope to the inner most `while` loop. Once the loop finishes, the memory used by the array is fair game and could be used by another variable which means your code is being hit hard by undefined behaviour. That you're getting any recognisable words at the end is down to pure luck.

So make a copy of it using either of these methods

```
temp -> termName = strdup(word);
```

or

```
temp -> termName = malloc(strlen(word)+1); // Always remember to allocate enough space for the NUL terminating character
strcpy(temp->termName, word);
```

And don't forget to free it too.

The reason why you're also not seeing the count go up, which in theory it should do since the `word` passed in will be the same string as in the list node, is because your check to see if the word already exists in the list is wrong.

The check to see if a string is identical is right, but you'll never trigger it because the `while` loop only checks that the string is after the current node.

```
    while ((iter -> next != NULL) && (strcmp(iter -> termName, word) > 0)) {
```

It'd make more sense to move this block of code outside of the `while` loop

```
if (strcmp(iter -> termName, word) == 0) {
    iter -> occur += 1;
    return root;
}
```

Looking at it in more detail, the whole `else` part of your `insert` routine can't work as it currently is written.

Imagine if you were to insert into it the following strings: "A" "C" and "E". Your code will add them in reverse order, so you'd get "E", "C", "A" in your output.

If you then try adding "D", it'll put it after "C". It'll start by comparing it with "D" and `strcmp` will return a positive number. Then it'll compare it with "C" and the loop will stop as that returns a negative number. You then add "D" *after* "C".

As per the previous block `if((strcmp(root-> termName, word)) < 0)`, when `strcmp` returns a negative value you want to insert the new node before the one you're comparing. But you can't do that as you don't know what the previous node was.

So by combining those two bits of code, add in some tracking of the of the previous node and a few other tweaks, your `insert` function becomes:

```
term * insert(term * root, char * word) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
        root -> next = NULL;
        root -> termName = strdup(word);
        root -> occur = 1;
        return root;
    } else {
        term * iter = root, *last = NULL;
        while ((iter != NULL) && (strcmp(iter -> termName, word) > 0)) {        
            last = iter;
            iter = iter -> next;
        }

        if ((iter)&&(strcmp(iter -> termName, word) == 0)) {
            iter -> occur += 1;
            return root;
        } else if (last == NULL) {
            term * temp = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
            temp -> termName = strdup(word);
            temp -> occur = 1;
            temp -> next = root;
            return temp;
        } else {
            term * temp = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
            temp -> next = last -> next;
            last -> next = temp;
            temp -> termName = strdup(word);
            temp -> occur = 1;
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

So it is now checking to find the node where it is no longer alphabetically before the current node. If the node has the same word, then update the `occur`. If we've not yet set `last` that means we're at the beginning, so prepend the new node at the beginning and return it. Lastly we know that the `last` node is after this word and the `iter` node is before it (or doesn't exist), so we insert the new word in between.

Comment: strdup(word) worked. It doesn't print just three words anymore. But still there are some words which printed two times and some occur values are extremely high. Another problem is linked list isn't in alphabetical order. (I moved the block you said to move outside of the loop)

Comment: The whole logic of the `else` part of your `insert` function is fundamentally wrong upon closer inspection. I'll update my answer with more details cos it's probably going to be too long for a comment.

Comment: I am really grateful for your detailed response. I understood the logic.